# Error in python: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

When I am running in python the command
`b =data[data>threshold_1]`
where data is an array, It 's running well.
But when I add a second condition 
`b =a[a>threshold_1 and a<threshold_2]`
I have the aforementioned error. Why is happening?

Comment: Change the "and" for a "&" symbol

Comment: already done it and it is not working. I got the same error.

Comment: The question answered following the post 'Condition on numpy arrays' suggested by @Ashwini Chaudhary.

Comment: The linked post suggests using `np.logical_and`, but that's a lot to type, and I'm lazy. Just change the `and` to `&` and put parens around the terms: `a[(a > threshold_1) & (a < threshold_2)]`.

Comment: @jme Worked as well. Thank you.